# Can meta description content be exactly the same as the page content?

Tags: seo, content, meta-description

I have a web site with very limited amount of content on every page (only two sentences), each page represents a product from our 150 products repository. The SEO is very important to me and I don't want to risk anything.

Is it OK if the content of the page (these two sentences) be included also in the `description` meta tag on the page, exactly as it is, or is there any restriction to the page content and `meta`-`description` content from the SEO point of view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Although the point of a  tag is to make a suggestion to Google as to what you'd like to see on the SERP result description. If you have only 2 lines of content - it's a no brainer for Google and the tag is redundant. It will just scrape the description from the page.

Also be warned that pages that are too 'thin' on content will either not be indexed or are likely to receive a penalty.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably ok to have the same content on your page and in your `meta tag` of type `description`.

But from SEO point of view I would not do it like this - I would keep this `meta tag` and the content of your page separate from each other with regards to intent and purpose.

The text used in the `meta tag` of type `description` will probably display in the SERPs (search engine result pages) so it should be optimised to entice the user to click on the link. This is where you give the user a reason as to why he/she should click on the link to your page. Apparently the text in this `meta tag` is not used as a ranking factor to get higher rankings in the SERPs.

The text that is part of your page's content should be a decent description as to what you have on your page. Try and optimise this text for SEO purposes by using your well researched keywords as part of the content.

Answer (score -1):

1. Each of your Meta Description should be unique. And you can't take your product content to your meta content.
2. Your Meta Description shouldn't be more than 160 characters (with space) long. So, write something unique as your Meta Description that represents your product and entice the possible buyers.

Comment: FYI, don't call yourself an SEO expert on a site about SEO.